# Restriction the results for relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have simple tables Post and Comment and I am doing query:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Post');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.made = :made')
    ->setParameter('made', 1)
    ->leftJoin('p.comments', 'c')
    ->andWhere('c.isAdmin = :isAdmin')
    ->setParameter('isAdmin', 1)
    ->getQuery();

$results = $query->getResult();

foreach($results as $post) {
    echo $post->getId(); // this clause where (->where('p.made = :made')) working ok
    foreach($post->getComments() as $comments) {
       echo $comment->getId(); //this clause where (->andWhere('c.isAdmin = :isAdmin')) not working. This return all results
    }
}
```

So how can I use clause where in query with relations?

SQL:

```
SELECT 
  i0_.id AS id0, 
  i0_.made AS made1, 
  i0_.name AS name2, 
FROM 
  post i0_ 
  LEFT JOIN comment i1_ ON i0_.id = i1_.comment_id 
WHERE 
  i0_.made = ? 
  AND i1_.isAdmin = ?
```

Comment: Could you tell us about `c.isAdmin`? Is a boolean, an integer, or ... ?

Comment: Integer, but does not matter. This is only example.

Comment: It does matters, it does. BTW, could you paste your query log?

Comment: Just when I use in leftJoin where clause she never works. In this example getComments() get all results.

Comment: Again, could you paste sql log? You could find into dev.log of your application

Comment: I'm quite sure $post->getComments() call a new request.

Comment: @Smashou yes. So how can i make it? I must doing two query?

Comment: @courriel994455 I think my answer will work, give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add a select method in your request:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
->select(["c", "p"])
->where('p.made = :made')
->setParameter('made', 1)
->leftJoin('p.comments', 'c')
->andWhere('c.isAdmin = :isAdmin')
->setParameter('isAdmin', 1)
->getQuery();
```

Is it better ?

This works better because you specify to hydrate the whole objects rather than just Ids.